# Scope of global array in function

Tags: php

I'm trying to add to, and print the contents of a global array that is being accessed within an individual function.

PHP

```
<?php

// Globals for data cache
$city_array = [];

/*  printArray
 *  print the value of global array
*/
function printArray() {
    print_r($city_array);
}

printArray();

?>
```

This is returning an error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: city_array in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/donorsearch/process.php on line 6

How can I get access to this global array within this local function?

Answer (score 0):

To access global variable in function you must use `global` to tell PHP you want that:

```
function printArray() {
    global $city_array;

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use `global`:

```
$city_array = [];
function printArray() {
    global $city_array
    print_r($city_array);
}
printArray();
```

Pass via function:

```
function printArray($array) {
    print_r($array);
}
$city_array = [];
printArray($city_array);
```